# Why Can’t Some Users Access My Website?

Tags: iis-8

My remote host uses Microsoft’s IIS 8 server.

I developed my code on a local Apache server, if this is relevant.

My problem: Some users report that when trying to access my site their browsers only display a page that shows the IIS 8 emblem, although most users do not have this access problem.

Is this my fault or must I speak to the host server’s management?

Addendum:
Here's ANOTHER thing: When I type into the URL my website preceded by the usual www. prefix, it too then sends me to the lame display IIS page; Only when I **omit** the prefix does it access my website properly!

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: You should ask those users to capture the complete URL they are using from the browser address bar. It might be that the root url does not load a default html page and that other users have a more complete path in their url. It could also be that the www is not mapped or something along those lines. In short it's all guess work until you can reproduce it and you can't reproduce it until you have some more information to go on (like a url).

Comment: Igor - I send emails to my many friends, where my "signature" contains my URL. Why then would the link work on most, but some users get the unintended MS display instead?

Comment: Igor - I added an addendum to my question.

Comment: Your website is configured for name prefixed without `www.` but otherwise it goes to the standard `IIS` page. Configure your website for both `www.` prefixed and non-prefixed. Some browsers omit the `www.` prefix even when typed or not. Some browsers add the prefix. Just make sure your website is configured for both. In Apache, there is a `ServerAlias` directive. Check if `IIS` has something similar.

Answer (score 0):

As alvits points out above, some browsers attach the ww prefix, some don't. There is a workaround if the server runs Apache (search "www. prefix server"), but I found none for IIS-8.

Because my emails have my website as part of my signature, and because the www. prefix will fail in linking to my website, I get around this by using the http:// prefix instead. That would be the same as just typing into the URL the website without the www. prefix. And note that were I to just use in my signature the website name without the www. prefix - that too would not work because some browsers automatically do add that prefix anyhow!